Implementing payapl on a angular application
I've been trying to get a sandbox enviorment app from paypal to work on my Angular App.
I keep getting the error 422, no clue why.
Everything works smoothly,  I login on the test account, but I keep getting the 422 erorr.
Yes my user id is correct
I've added the paypal reposne at the bottom.
I am from Bosnia.




import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

declare var paypal: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-paypal',
  templateUrl: './paypal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./paypal.component.css']
})
export class PaypalComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('paypal', { static: true }) paypalElement!: ElementRef;

  product = {
    price: 1,
    description: 'Used Couch, decent condition',
  };

  paidfor = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    paypal
      .Buttons({
        createOrder: (data: any, actions: any) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                description: this.product.description,
                amount: {
                  currency_code: 'USD', // Changed currency code to EUR
                  value: this.product.price.toString(), // Ensure price is a string
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },
        onApprove: async (data: any, actions: any) => {
          try {
            const order = await actions.order.capture();
            this.paidfor = true;
            console.log(order);
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error capturing order:', error);
          }
        },
        onError: (err: any) => {
          console.error('PayPal error:', err);
        }
      })
      .render(this.paypalElement.nativeElement);
  }
}


 <script src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=USER_ID&currency=USD&debug=true"></script>




// Here is the json paypal response:

{
  "additional_properties": {},
  "body": {
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "details": [
      {
        "issue": "COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION",
        "description": "Transaction cannot be processed due to a possible compliance violation. To get more information about the transaction, call Customer Support."
      }
    ],
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "f1358601be5d7",
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION",
        "rel": "information_link",
        "method": "GET"
      }
    ]
  },
  "duration_time": "xxxxxx",
  "header": {
    "APPLICATION_ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": "xxxxxx",
    "BORDER-IP": "xxxxxx",
    "CALLER_ACCT_NUM": "SYFYX283TNPKN",
    "Date": "Wed, 11 Sep 2024 15:01:51 GMT",
    "Keep-Alive": "xxxxxx",
    "PROCESSING-IP": "xxxxxx",
    "SERVER_INFO": "xxxxxx",
    "Server-Timing": "xxxxxx",
    "paypal-debug-id": "f1358601be5d7"
  },
  "status": 422
}





I think it has to do with the price you are sending (or the format of the price). Show us the network response from PayPal in case there are more details there.

Just added it on the post, thanks for the response!

You beautiful creature, I love you!!

It is a country problem.
PayPal Checkout UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY: COMPLIANCE_VIOLATION
For future tags:
Albania, Algeria, Antigua and Barbuda, Barbados, Belize, Bosnia and Herzegovina, Dominica, Egypt, Fiji, French Polynesia, Grenada, Lesotho, Malawi, New Caledonia, Palau, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Seychelles, Trinidad and Tobago, Turks and Caicos
These countries could have the same issue I faced. Check the documentation to fix.
